# Can Siddhi CEP library execution plans run against Kafka Streams?

Tags: siddhi, apache-kafka-streams

I want to run Siddhi CEP library with KafkaStreams, but it looks like it already has its own concept of "streams".  How do I plug in KafkaStreams to enable the Siddhi execution plans run on KafkaStreams instead?

EDIT addressing Dilini's comment >>

Referring to :
[Kafka Streams documentation](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#streams)

Kafka Streams does not currently have a tight integration with a CEP framework that I have found.  Apache Flink, for instance, has it's own Flink CEP.  So, I'd envision using Siddhi CEP as an abstraction layer on top of Kafka Streams with a tight integration between the two technologies.  For example,

1. Creating a Siddhi CEP Stream would automatically create the Kafka Topic and Kafka Stream to stream the events posted to that topic.
2. Creating Siddhi CEP output streams would do create Kafka Topic and publish to it
3. Siddhi CEP's "event table" might be either a local, Kafka Streams "state store" or a Kafka Topic, since they are essentially a replicated, partitioned data store.  This, instead of using a RDBMS or in-memory event table, etc.
4. Siddhi CEP Execution Plans complex event queries would forward to Kafka Streams Processor APIs that do map(), filter(), and join Kafka Streams to check for patterns, etc..

I'm trying to understand why I'd want to have multiple "stream" frameworks, especially, if I already have Kafka Streams in my environment.

Comment: I don't know Siddhi CEP and it seems that you question is rather broad. Did you familiarize yourself with Kafka Streams? Did you try anything to integrate both? If yes, where did you hit problems?

Comment: I would like to understand the need of integrating Siddhi with KafkaStreams... Do you mind explaining the usecase a bit?

Comment: Please see edits, Dilini.